# Error “La propiedad value no existe en el tipo evento”

Tags: angular, typescript, vscode

Estaba haciendo pruebas con el `Two-way Data Binding` de angular, pero me encuentro con un problema, y es que typescript no es capaz de reconocer la propiedad `value` del evento (`$event.target.value`). He estado investigando respecto al problema, pero las soluciones son para cuando ya recibes el evento en un metodo, lo cual no me sirve porque si paso un evento, me da error ya que la variable en el fichero de typescript espera un `string` del texto que se ingresa. Dejare

Variable que recibe el evento y lo coloca en un `textinput` en un fichero `.ts` y variable que envia el resultado:

```
  @Input() contenidoMarkDown: string = ''
  @Output() changeMarkdown: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>()
```

HTML:

```
<div (change)="changeMarkdown.emit($event.target.value)">
    <div [(ngModel)]="contenidoMarkDown"></div>
</div>
```

Enlaces relacionados a mi problema (pero no me sirve, ya que yo necesitaría tomar el valor desde el `value` del `HTML`):

- [property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-in-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321326/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-in-typescript/44321394)
- [keyboardevent-property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53987954/keyboardevent-property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget)

Código de prueba: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n9mlz9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Encontré como respuesta por parte del instructor que:

> $event.target es un HTMLElement el cual no tiene garantizado una
> propiedad value, de ahí el error. Una solución es pasar el $event
> directamente al metodo.

Lo cual esta bien, pero no me sirve, porque en el curso si le toma este value, además de que, como dije en un principio, con un `Two-way Data Binding` u casos puntuales, necesito especificar el tipo de dato a recibir, además de que no me gusta andar recibiendo todo el evento en los métodos, cuando solo quiero recibir una propiedad en concreto.

Su ejemplo (es independiente al control, para su ejemplo era un `textarea`):

HTML:

```
<div (input)="inputDiv($event)"></div>
```

.ts:

```
inputDiv(evento): void {
  const texto = evento.target.value;
  this.contenidoMarkDown = texto
  this.changeMarkdown.emit(texto)
}
```

Captura del codigo en el curso (sin usar `two-way databinding`, que igual me tiraba el error):

```
HTLM
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
.ts
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `value` no existe en el contexto de `HTMLElement`. Sin embargo, puedes forzar esa llamada asumiendo que el elemento que estás llamando sí posee dicha propiedad. Por ejemplo, realizando un **type assertion**, así: `event.target as HTMLInputElement`, el cuál sí tendrá la propiedad `value`. Sin embargo, en el ejemplo estás usando un `<div>` el cual es recibido como `HTMLDivElement`, un tipo que no posee la propiedad `value` al igual que `HTMLElement`.

Comment: Podrías comentarlo a modo de respuesta con un ejemplo de este type assertion en el evento del HTML que me que solucione el error, así también marco la respuesta como correcta en caso de que me elimine el error.

Answer (score 0):

Como te comento @KBeDev, el `div` no contiene `value`.

Con este cambio te funcionara como esperas.

```
<div>
    <textarea
   (change)="changeMarkdown.emit(contenidoMarkDown)"
  [(ngModel)]="contenidoMarkDown"></textarea>
</div
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eq3am8?file=src/app/componente/componente.component.html).

Comment: Estare haciendo pruebas y en caso de que todo funcione bien, lo marcare como respuesta. Lo que me resulta raro, es que en el curso si le reconozca la propiedad value, y a mi no, cosa que espero no me genere problemas mas adelante, porque es una propiedad muy frecuente de usar. Tuve un problema similar asignando este value de un evento a una variable (evento (input)), no me lo tomaba, y tuve que usar lo indicado por el instructor arriba en mi mensaje (y allí si era un textarea)

Comment: Puede ser que usara una versión anterior de angular o que estuvieras perdiendo algún detalle. Sin la referencia me es imposible hacerte un comentario sobre como lo implementó. Si publicas alguna captura del curso donde muestra el ejemplo será mas fácil orientarte.

Comment: Ya añadí las capturas del código del curso. Como aclare, en ese punto ya me marcaba en rojo el querer mandar un value por el textarea.

Answer (score 0):

De hecho la propagación de un evento permite capturarlo desde los padres por lo que puedes poner el change en el padre y el te dara el elemento que lo lanzo ejemplo:

```html
<div onchange="javascript: console.log(event.target.name+' = '+event.target.value);">
  <input type="text" name="primero"/>
  <input type="text" name="segundo"/>
</div>
```